# call another testcase from within a testcase in Test::Unit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara, testunit

Is there a way to call another testcase inside a testcase?

```
test "simple" do
  # ..
end

test "large" do
  # execute simple test
  # ..
end
```

Just defining a method that both testcases call doesn't work. I'm using `Capybara` and I think it needs to be run in the scope of the *test block*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I can just use regular methods. The problem for some reason had to do with the *Headless* gem. I reverted to using Xvfb directly.